# Modifying kwargs vs modifying **kwargs inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

In the following situation

```
def f(kwargs):
    kwargs['a'] = 44
    print('a: {}, b: {}'.format(kwargs['a'], kwargs['b']))
```

the dict provided to `f()` will be modified as expected.

That is:

```
given_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
f(given_dict)           # prints     a: 44, b: 2
print(given_dict)       # prints     {'a': 44, 'b': 2}
                                            ^
                                            |__ changed
```

However, when using the code below, the dict does not get modified:

```
def g(**kwargs):
    kwargs['a'] = 44    
    print('a: {}, b: {}'.format(kwargs['a'], kwargs['b']))

given_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
g(**given_dict)            # prints     a: 44, b: 2
print(given_dict)          # prints     {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                                            ^
                                            |__ unchanged
```

---

Why is it that `g()` didn't modify the given dict just like `f()` did?
I was expecting that `kwargs['a'] = 44` would have the same effect in both functions.